# Upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04.03LTS : No entry in /run/user

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, permissions

I upgraded recently from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS. This went mostly fine, but I experience a number of issues that seem to be related to permissions (e.g. nm-applet not allowing access to normal user, dconf-critical errors with evince).

Although I found a number of comments on these individual problems, I noticed today that my `/run/user` directory is empty. There should be a directory with my user ID, I believe. Maybe this is the common origin of the problems?

I find on another machine that has exactly the same Ubuntu version installed (but went along a different upgrade path) that this is indeed the case,  `/run/user/1000` exits and has many entries.

Can someone help with why I don't get this directory, and how I could fix it?

Thanks, Oliver.

Comment: Maybe also of significance and of similar origin: 1) `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is not set on the upgraded machine. On the other computer that I mentioned it contains `/run/user/1000` as expected. 2) `/var/run` is not a symbolic link on the machine with the problem, whereas it is to `/run` on the other.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://laclaro.wordpress.com/2014/04/17/upstart-or-systemd-in-ubuntu-14-04-both/) and the reference given therein. Adding the line `session optional pam_systemd.so` to `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` solved all the issues I mentioned (I am using the lightdm display manager).